# LIKE COALESCE in Spring JPA does not work

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

So my problem is the following:

I have a table I want a filter to apply to. This filter should call a query which finds based on the given information the reports.

This is how my query looks:

```
   @Query("SELECT r FROM Report r WHERE r.importanceLevel = COALESCE(importance,'%')" +
        "AND r.source = COALESCE(source,'%')" +
        "AND r.resolvedStatus = COALESCE(resolvedStatus,'%')" +
        "AND r.header LIKE + '%' COALESCE(query,'%') + '%'")
  List<Report> getReportsByAppliedFilter(@Param("importance") int importance, @Param("source") String source,
                                       @Param("resolvedStatus") int resolvedStatus, @Param("query") String query);
```

Problem is: IntelliJ does not like the following:

```
 LIKE + '%' COALESCE(query,'%') + '%'
```

Error:  expected, got +

Do you have any idea how to solve this otherwise?

Comment: Why don't you take another look at that expression? Why are you trying to concatenate the `LIKE` keyword with the `'%'` string? And what do you expect it to do with `'%' COALESCE(...`, without an operator between `'%'` and `COALESCE`? --- If you want to mimic Homer Simpson now, it would be appropriate: *DOH!* --- I've mimiced Homer a few times myself over the years.

Comment: @Andreas http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=25086 here they use it too.

Comment: and im not sure where you see an operator missing...

Comment: `LIKE + '%' COALESCE` is not the same as `LIKE '%' + COALESCE`. Look at your link again. They did it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, time to go to bed. You dont use + for concat , you use concat():

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Report r WHERE r.importanceLevel = COALESCE(importance,'%')" +
        "AND r.source = COALESCE(source,'%')" +
        "AND r.resolvedStatus = COALESCE(resolvedStatus,'%')" +
        "AND r.header LIKE  CONCAT('%', COALESCE(query,'%'), '%')")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column name is `request_status` and table name is `connections` then use **COALESCE** like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT connections.id, COALESCE(connections.request_status,'') as request_status.... ", nativeQuery = true)
List<ZXYType> xysfunction();
```

Here if `request_status` is null then it will be replaced by an empty string.